# HERE maps searchEngine.search always gives error FORBIDDEN

Tags: android, here-api

HERE map SearchEngine in Android Explore SDK always gives error "FORBIDDEN", even though map drawing works properly.

With Android Explore SDK heresdk-explore-android-4.13.4.0.11034.aar, when running the example Search on both Android Studio emulator and on a Galaxy s22, it correctly shows a map of Berlin but the SearchCallback .onSearchCompleted() of searchEngine.search()  always gives SearchError "FORBIDDEN"

and it's the same problem for  onSuggestCompleted() of  searchEngine.suggest() - it  always gives SearchError "FORBIDDEN"

In Android Studio console, it has this error when doing a search:
E/SearchErrorConvert: [ERROR] SearchErrorConvert - Search error: web::http::http_exception, what: {"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}
,value: 403

Despite this error, since I can see a map of Berlin OK, I guess my accessKeyID and accessKeySecret must be correct.

I have HERE base plan including billing with a credit card, and got my access key ID and Secret in October 2022 when I created credentials using OAuth and have been able to create and see maps, markers and polylines ever since.

Here's my code, copied from the Android Explore SDK Search example (with my real accessKeyID and accessKeySecret only hidden here in this post).
The error is produced from searchEngine.search(query, searchOptions, querySearchCallback)  from  searchInViewport()
and error is produced from searchEngine.suggest() from autoSuggestExample()

```
private void initializeHERESDK() {
    // Set your credentials for the HERE SDK.
    String accessKeyID = "<id>";
    String accessKeySecret = "<secret>";
    SDKOptions options = new SDKOptions(accessKeyID, accessKeySecret);
    try {
        Context context = this;
        SDKNativeEngine.makeSharedInstance(context, options);
    } catch (InstantiationErrorException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Initialization of HERE SDK failed: " + e.error.name());
    }
}
```

public class SearchExample {

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = SearchExample.class.getName();

private final Context context;
private final MapView mapView;
private final MapCamera camera;
private final List<MapMarker> mapMarkerList = new ArrayList<>();
private SearchEngine searchEngine;

public SearchExample(Context context, MapView mapView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mapView = mapView;
    camera = mapView.getCamera();
    double distanceInMeters = 1000 * 10;
    MapMeasure mapMeasureZoom = new MapMeasure(MapMeasure.Kind.DISTANCE, distanceInMeters);
    camera.lookAt(new GeoCoordinates(52.520798, 13.409408), mapMeasureZoom);

    try {
        searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
    } catch (InstantiationErrorException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Initialization of SearchEngine failed: " + e.error.name());
    }

    setTapGestureHandler();
    setLongPressGestureHandler();

    Toast.makeText(context,"Long press on map to get the address for that position using reverse geocoding.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onSearchButtonClicked() {
    // Search for "Pizza" and show the results on the map.
    searchExample();

    // Search for auto suggestions and log the results to the console.
    autoSuggestExample();
}

public void onGeocodeButtonClicked() {
    // Search for the location that belongs to an address and show it on the map.
    geocodeAnAddress();
}

private void searchExample() {
    String searchTerm = "Pizza";

    Toast.makeText(context,"Searching in viewport: " + searchTerm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    searchInViewport(searchTerm);
}

private void geocodeAnAddress() {
    // Set map to expected location.
    GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = new GeoCoordinates(52.53086, 13.38469);
    double distanceInMeters = 1000 * 7;
    MapMeasure mapMeasureZoom = new MapMeasure(MapMeasure.Kind.DISTANCE, distanceInMeters);
    camera.lookAt(geoCoordinates, mapMeasureZoom);

    String queryString = "Invalidenstraße 116, Berlin";

    Toast.makeText(context,"Finding locations for: " + queryString
            + ". Tap marker to see the coordinates. Check the logs for the address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    geocodeAddressAtLocation(queryString, geoCoordinates);
}

private void setTapGestureHandler() {
    mapView.getGestures().setTapListener(touchPoint -> pickMapMarker(touchPoint));
}

private void setLongPressGestureHandler() {
    mapView.getGestures().setLongPressListener((gestureState, touchPoint) -> {
        if (gestureState == GestureState.BEGIN) {
            GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = mapView.viewToGeoCoordinates(touchPoint);
            if (geoCoordinates == null) {
                return;
            }
            addPoiMapMarker(geoCoordinates);
            getAddressForCoordinates(geoCoordinates);
        }
    });
}

private void getAddressForCoordinates(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates) {
    SearchOptions reverseGeocodingOptions = new SearchOptions();
    reverseGeocodingOptions.languageCode = LanguageCode.EN_GB;
    reverseGeocodingOptions.maxItems = 1;

    searchEngine.search(geoCoordinates, reverseGeocodingOptions, addressSearchCallback);
}

private final SearchCallback addressSearchCallback = new SearchCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSearchCompleted(@Nullable SearchError searchError, @Nullable List<Place> list) {
        if (searchError != null) {
            showDialog("Reverse geocoding", "Error: " + searchError.toString());
            return;
        }

        // If error is null, list is guaranteed to be not empty.
        showDialog("Reverse geocoded address:", list.get(0).getAddress().addressText);
    }
};

private void pickMapMarker(final Point2D point2D) {
    float radiusInPixel = 2;
    mapView.pickMapItems(point2D, radiusInPixel, new MapViewBase.PickMapItemsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPickMapItems(@Nullable PickMapItemsResult pickMapItemsResult) {
            if (pickMapItemsResult == null) {
                return;
            }

            List<MapMarker> mapMarkerList = pickMapItemsResult.getMarkers();
            if (mapMarkerList.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }
            MapMarker topmostMapMarker = mapMarkerList.get(0);

            Metadata metadata = topmostMapMarker.getMetadata();
            if (metadata != null) {
                CustomMetadataValue customMetadataValue = metadata.getCustomValue("key_search_result");
                if (customMetadataValue != null) {
                    SearchResultMetadata searchResultMetadata = (SearchResultMetadata) customMetadataValue;
                    String title = searchResultMetadata.searchResult.getTitle();
                    String vicinity = searchResultMetadata.searchResult.getAddress().addressText;
                    showDialog("Picked Search Result",title + ". Vicinity: " + vicinity);
                    return;
                }
            }

            showDialog("Picked Map Marker",
                    "Geographic coordinates: " +
                            topmostMapMarker.getCoordinates().latitude + ", " +
                            topmostMapMarker.getCoordinates().longitude);
        }
    });
}

private void searchInViewport(String queryString) {
    clearMap();

    GeoBox viewportGeoBox = getMapViewGeoBox();
    TextQuery.Area queryArea = new TextQuery.Area(viewportGeoBox);
    TextQuery query = new TextQuery(queryString, queryArea);

    SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions();
    searchOptions.languageCode = LanguageCode.EN_US;
    searchOptions.maxItems = 30;

    searchEngine.search(query, searchOptions, querySearchCallback);
}

private final SearchCallback querySearchCallback = new SearchCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSearchCompleted(@Nullable SearchError searchError, @Nullable List<Place> list) {
        if (searchError != null) {
            showDialog("Search", "Error: " + searchError.toString());
            return;
        }

        // If error is null, list is guaranteed to be not empty.
        showDialog("Search", "Results: " + list.size());

        // Add new marker for each search result on map.
        for (Place searchResult : list) {
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            metadata.setCustomValue("key_search_result", new SearchResultMetadata(searchResult));
            // Note: getGeoCoordinates() may return null only for Suggestions.
            addPoiMapMarker(searchResult.getGeoCoordinates(), metadata);
        }
    }
};

private static class SearchResultMetadata implements CustomMetadataValue {

    public final Place searchResult;

    public SearchResultMetadata(Place searchResult) {
        this.searchResult = searchResult;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getTag() {
        return "SearchResult Metadata";
    }
}

private final SuggestCallback autosuggestCallback = new SuggestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuggestCompleted(@Nullable SearchError searchError, @Nullable List<Suggestion> list) {
        if (searchError != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Autosuggest Error: " + searchError.name());
            return;
        }

        // If error is null, list is guaranteed to be not empty.
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Autosuggest results: " + list.size());

        for (Suggestion autosuggestResult : list) {
            String addressText = "Not a place.";
            Place place = autosuggestResult.getPlace();
            if (place != null) {
                addressText = place.getAddress().addressText;
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Autosuggest result: " + autosuggestResult.getTitle() +
                    " addressText: " + addressText);
        }
    }
};

private void autoSuggestExample() {
    GeoCoordinates centerGeoCoordinates = getMapViewCenter();

    SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions();
    searchOptions.languageCode = LanguageCode.EN_US;
    searchOptions.maxItems = 5;

    TextQuery.Area queryArea = new TextQuery.Area(centerGeoCoordinates);

    // Simulate a user typing a search term.
    searchEngine.suggest(
            new TextQuery("p", // User typed "p".
                    queryArea),
            searchOptions,
            autosuggestCallback);

    searchEngine.suggest(
            new TextQuery("pi", // User typed "pi".
                    queryArea),
            searchOptions,
            autosuggestCallback);

    searchEngine.suggest(
            new TextQuery("piz", // User typed "piz".
                    queryArea),
            searchOptions,
            autosuggestCallback);
}

private void geocodeAddressAtLocation(String queryString, GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates) {
    clearMap();

    AddressQuery query = new AddressQuery(queryString, geoCoordinates);

    SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions();
    options.languageCode = LanguageCode.DE_DE;
    options.maxItems = 30;

    searchEngine.search(query, options, geocodeAddressSearchCallback);
}

private final SearchCallback geocodeAddressSearchCallback = new SearchCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSearchCompleted(SearchError searchError, List<Place> list) {
        if (searchError != null) {
            showDialog("Geocoding", "Error: " + searchError.toString());
            return;
        }

        for (Place geocodingResult : list) {
            // Note: getGeoCoordinates() may return null only for Suggestions.
            GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = geocodingResult.getGeoCoordinates();
            Address address = geocodingResult.getAddress();
            String locationDetails = address.addressText
                    + ". GeoCoordinates: " + geoCoordinates.latitude
                    + ", " + geoCoordinates.longitude;

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "GeocodingResult: " + locationDetails);
            addPoiMapMarker(geoCoordinates);
        }

        showDialog("Geocoding result","Size: " + list.size());
    }
};

private void addPoiMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates) {
    MapMarker mapMarker = createPoiMapMarker(geoCoordinates);
    mapView.getMapScene().addMapMarker(mapMarker);
    mapMarkerList.add(mapMarker);
}

private void addPoiMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, Metadata metadata) {
    MapMarker mapMarker = createPoiMapMarker(geoCoordinates);
    mapMarker.setMetadata(metadata);
    mapView.getMapScene().addMapMarker(mapMarker);
    mapMarkerList.add(mapMarker);
}

private MapMarker createPoiMapMarker(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates) {
    MapImage mapImage = MapImageFactory.fromResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.poi);
    return new MapMarker(geoCoordinates, mapImage, new Anchor2D(0.5F, 1));
}

private GeoCoordinates getMapViewCenter() {
    return mapView.getCamera().getState().targetCoordinates;
}

private GeoBox getMapViewGeoBox() {
    int mapViewWidthInPixels = mapView.getWidth();
    int mapViewHeightInPixels = mapView.getHeight();
    Point2D bottomLeftPoint2D = new Point2D(0, mapViewHeightInPixels);
    Point2D topRightPoint2D = new Point2D(mapViewWidthInPixels, 0);

    GeoCoordinates southWestCorner = mapView.viewToGeoCoordinates(bottomLeftPoint2D);
    GeoCoordinates northEastCorner = mapView.viewToGeoCoordinates(topRightPoint2D);

    if (southWestCorner == null || northEastCorner == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("GeoBox creation failed, corners are null.");
    }

    // Note: This algorithm assumes an unrotated map view.
    return new GeoBox(southWestCorner, northEastCorner);
}

private void clearMap() {
    for (MapMarker mapMarker : mapMarkerList) {
        mapView.getMapScene().removeMapMarker(mapMarker);
    }
    mapMarkerList.clear();
}

private void showDialog(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Comment: On screen orientation change i get this same error. the search engine stop working strange issue. Were you able to find what is the issue and fix? my error is little different than yours 
[ERROR] SearchErrorConvert - Search error: pplx::task_canceled, what:

Comment: No, I haven't found a fix, @YLS. I'm hoping someone from HERE maps will see this post and look into the problem

Comment: Did you find any solution? Currently having the same issue, not sure if I need to enable something in the Developer platform.

Comment: No, @Wrakor. I'm still waiting for someone from HERE maps to respond to this post. When I contacted HERE maps, they told me that the way to proceed with technical issues is to post here in stackoverflow and that someone from HERE will, after a while, respond.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: "These credentials do not authorize access". If you see a map, it does not necessarily mean that the credentials are correct. For example, you can still see the map when there is no internet connection, because the map data was previously cached.

If you are 100% sure that you are using the correct credentials, you have to contact the HERE support. I just tested my credentials and they still work as expected.

Comment: Yes @Nusatad, it does seem to be a clear message.

However if I change the credentials by adding "XXX" to the value of  String accessKeyID  in initializeHERESDK(), running the example will not show any map and gives immediate error:

[ERROR] Authorization - Authorization fail. Failed to get token: 1

This seems to show that my credentials are used for map drawing and are correct.

The question is why these credentials don't work for the SearchEngine.

Comment: The map data is cached on the device using your credentials key as part of the path. This may explain it. Either way, you should contact the HERE team to check if there is an issue with your credentials.